# Explicitly set a tab for bounty links

Tags: bug, profile-page, bounties

Bounty section in the [user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=topactivity) contains a three tabs: active, offered, and earned. Every time when tab is switching the title is changes:

> [image: active]

> [image: offered]

> [image: earned]

But link in the title remains the same: to the bounty tab without explicit specifying the subtab (actually called “sort”). E.g. in the Community user [bounty tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties). In this scenario link from the title can refers to the different subtab (which is default, or last used, I don’t know). I.e. by clicking on the “Offered bounties” could be opened “active” subtab with empty items:

> [image: empty active]

Worth noting that full address already used here, for the [“View more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties&sort=offered)” link, where “sort” parameter has an explicit value “offered”.

I think following links (from the title and “view more”) should refer to the same place (with current sorting mode):

> [image: offered links]